# brake pedal hits bottom and mechanics say it's OK

Tags: brakes

I had tires installed and after that, I noticed the brake pedal hits bottom if I press it hard enough. While in "D".  The tire shop checked it and they say it's OK. There is no leak and fluid is tops. I had another repair shop look at it and they also say it's OK.

But brake pedal hitting bottom cannot be "OK", can it?

Nissan Altima 2016, both front and rear brakes are disc.

Comment: If you hit bottom by pressing hard, then release the pedal for a moment and press hard again, does it hit bottom again or not?

Comment: @MTA yes it always hits bottom, and I don't even have to press very hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that there are no leaks and that all brake hoses are intact, because you've been informed that there are no obvious problems.

If no one has bled your brakes yet, that should be your first step, performed by a competent mechanic and by Nissan's recommended brake bleeding procedure.

If that does not cure the problem, you must consider replacing your master cylinder because the brake pedal should not reach a hard stop under normal circumstances.

Before you drive this vehicle anywhere, make sure you are getting enough braking to make an emergency stop. If you are not, you should have it towed to a repair shop.

Comment: thank you, they did bleed already, and it brakes perfectly fine in all circumstances...  
they did check the master also, it's fine

I guess I will take it to a dealer